# Joining two tables on columns that don't equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a **equipment** table and a **downtime** table that I am wanting to join, I am wanting to display all the equipment and the downtime hours. If there is no downtime for a certain piece of equipment then I want to display a zero in the rows where value is null. This is what I have below. It only gives me the equipment that has downtime in the other table.

```
Select a.EquipNbr,
       ISNULL(Sum(a.Downtime),0)
From MobileDowntime (nolock) a
Join MblEquip (nolock) b on a.EquipNbr = b.EquipNbr
Where b.DelFlg = 0 and
      b.EquipNbr <> 'Clean Shop' and
      a.DateTm Between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1) 
Group By a.EquipNbr
Order by a.EquipNbr Asc
```

example of what I am trying to accomplish.. But the downtime table on captures data on change so there might not be any downtime for that piece of equipment for the whole month.
66 total pieces of equipment
Equipment / Downtime
1717         57
1723         0
1724         0
1725         50
1728         0
1734         35
1738         0

Comment: Hi @jShaffer , can you please tell us what database do you use? Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer or something else ? It would also be ok to put the desired result and some example data so we have the idea what is it you want exactly. Every info helps...

Comment: @JShaffer . . . I added the sql-server tag based on the syntax.

Comment: I am using MSSql

Comment: @JShaffer Have a look @ https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4b64e937c3d3e97fd28fe8981269c693

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos I tried that but it gives me a conversion failed error when converting the varchar value'Clean Shop' to data type int. It is the one odd ball in the equipment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join` and to move conditions on the `MobileDowntime` table to the `on` clause:

```
Select e.EquipNbr, coalesce(sum(md.Downtime), 0)
From MblEquip e left join
     MobileDowntime md
     on md.EquipNbr = e.EquipNbr and
        md.DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
where e.DelFlg = 0 and e.EquipNbr <> 'Clean Shop'  
group by e.EquipNbr 
order by e.EquipNbr Asc;
```

Note that I replaced your table aliases (hopefully correctly).  `a` and `b` are meaningless.  Instead, I used abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: I tried this example but it gives me the same results

Comment: I have a similar query but I have to sum 3 columns, it gives me the same kind of results Iike in the beginning. ```Select e.EquipNbr, coalesce(sum(mw.MaintTech1hours + mw.MaintTech2hours + mw.MaintTech3hours), 0) ReactiveHours From MblEquip e inner join MobileWorkOrder mw on mw.EquipNbr = e.EquipNbr and mw.DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1) where e.DelFlg = 0 and mw.Category = 'Reactive' group by e.EquipNbr order by ReactiveHours Desc;

Comment: @JShaffer . . . I think it is better to ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 1):

### Final Answer

```
Select b.EquipNbr, Sum(ISNULL((a.Downtime),0)) From MobileDowntime (nolock) a
RIGHT OUTER Join MblEquip (nolock) b on a.EquipNbr = b.EquipNbr
Where b.DelFlg = 0 and b.EquipNbr != 'Clean Shop' 
AND
(
a.datetm is null or 
(a.DateTm Between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) 
and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1) )
)
Group By b.EquipNbr Order by b.EquipNbr Asc
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=cc2c2cce139cda7d7c5878d6c967da34

### Step by Step

**Step 1:**

What you need to do is to use an outer-join, and a function that replaces NULL with zero (that you are doing).

So as a first step you would do the following:

```
Select b.EquipNbr, ISNULL((a.Downtime),0) From MobileDowntime (nolock) a
RIGHT OUTER Join MblEquip (nolock) b on a.EquipNbr = b.EquipNbr
```

**Step 2: With Group by**

Following, you can add the group by to  get  the following:

```
Select b.EquipNbr, Sum(ISNULL((a.Downtime),0)) From MobileDowntime (nolock) a
RIGHT OUTER Join MblEquip (nolock) b on a.EquipNbr = b.EquipNbr
Where b.DelFlg = 0 and b.EquipNbr != 'Clean Shop' 
Group By b.EquipNbr Order by b.EquipNbr Asc
```

The final part is the where condition using the dates.

### Update

The conversion error I think was because of the numerical comparison `!=` . 
I did an experiment and converted the Varchar to Int.

Then I changed the `!=` to `not like`.

```
Select b.EquipNbr, Sum(ISNULL((a.Downtime),0)) From MobileDowntime (nolock) a
RIGHT OUTER Join MblEquip (nolock) b on a.EquipNbr = b.EquipNbr
Where b.DelFlg = 0 and b.EquipNbr not like 'Clean Shop' 
AND
(
a.datetm is null or 
(a.DateTm Between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) 
and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1) )
)

Group By b.EquipNbr Order by b.EquipNbr Asc
```

Comment: I believe the OP already uses the function that replaces NULL with zero: `ISNULL(Sum(a.Downtime),0)`

Comment: @VBokšić I modified my answer to account for this. I've also added a fiddle.

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos I tried that but it gives me a conversion failed error when converting the varchar value'Clean Shop' to data type int. It is the one odd ball in the equipment

Comment: @JShaffer could you give us your create statements? I tried adding clean shop and am not getting the conversion error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=cc2c2cce139cda7d7c5878d6c967da34

Comment: @JShaffer Any chance for the SQL create statements?

Comment: I don't have access to the create statements.

Comment: @JShaffer A I changed the `!=` to `not like` . This might fix the issue with the conversion.

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos I have a similar query but I have to sum 3 columns, it gives me the same kind of results Iike in the beginning. ```Select e.EquipNbr, coalesce(sum(mw.MaintTech1hours + mw.MaintTech2hours + mw.MaintTech3hours), 0) ReactiveHours
From MblEquip e inner join
    MobileWorkOrder mw
     on mw.EquipNbr = e.EquipNbr and
        mw.DateTm between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
where e.DelFlg = 0 and mw.Category = 'Reactive'
group by e.EquipNbr 
order by ReactiveHours Desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer join in which it will show null when there is no downtime hours